# airflow: practical limit on the number of DAGS

Tags: airflow

What is the practical limit on the number of DAGS in an airflow system?

We are seeing severe delays after a couple of hundred DAGS are created.

Is anyone running 1000's of DAGS?

Comment: I, too, have severe lags between tasks. The problem is the scheduler cause a lot of my tasks are executed in 10's of seconds. We currently have about 150 dags separated in one file each

Comment: I would add to this question whether there is a practical limit on the number of tasks per DAG too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you run Airflow and how much resources you provide it. You can run Airflow in a distributed mode with Celery and Master and Worker having high memory and vCores, if you have huge number of tasks.